# Django Admin shows "(nothing)"

Tags: django-admin

I want to show in the app/model admin the columns of the model but with some customization. These 3 'tar', 'per_hor','per_tar' have choices in their modelfield.

First I wrote this code:

```
class ValoresAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('fecha', 'tar', 'per_hor','per_tar')
  list_filter = ('fecha','tar','per_tar','per_hor')
  date_hierarchy = 'fecha'
  fieldsets = (
    (None, {
        'fields': ('fecha',('tar', 'per_hor', 'per_tar'))
    }),
    (None, {
        'fields': ('feu', 'coef_perf','sah', 'pmh','carg_cap')
    }),
)
```

I shows the verbose name of the column but the values is always "(nothing)" on the filter page but if I enter the change form they display correctly their value (their choide).

I read some and decided to create methods like these ones and call them in the list_display:

```
def get_tar(Self):
 return self.get_tar_display()
def get_per_hor(Self):
 return self.get_per_hor_display()
def get_per_tar(Self):
 return self.get_per_tar_display()

get_tar_display.short_description = 'Tarifa'
get_per_hor_display.short_description = 'Periodo horario'
get_per_tar_display.short_description = 'Periodo tarifario'
```

Now the filter page will display columns named as the short description **BUT** with the real value of the field instead of theirs "choice value".

Addiotionally if I mark 'per_tar' as non editable it will show also "(nothing)" in the change from instead of it´s stored value.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Diving in internet I found the answer here:

http://thinkingnectar.com/2009/django-get_foo_display-behaviour-with-characters-and-integer-fields/

The post comment that when the field is char type, the choice key should be a string but when it´s an integer field it should be an interger!
Here was my problem! Changing strings to integer made it work.